# Is there any way to trigger storyboard on event in View?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Button:

```
    <Button x:Name="button" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnButtonClick}">
        <Button.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection RotationZ="50"/>
        </Button.Projection>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="320"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

And I use MVVM pattern so after click on the button, the method is called. I want also to start a storyboard but I found only this solution for MVVM pattern, because I can't reference Storyboard in my ViewModel (so I can't start it there).

Is there any way to modify this Storyboard to start only on button click? Now it starts when the application starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple of ways you can do it - define your *Storyboard* in resources and then just begin from code, use *VisualStates* for this within button's *Style* or even do everything in xaml by using *Behaviors* extension. The latter can look like this (first add reference to *Behaviors XAML*):

```xml
<!--add needed namespaces-->
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:icore="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:imedia="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"

<Button x:Name="button" >
    <Button.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection RotationZ="50"/>
    </Button.Projection>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <icore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button}">
            <imedia:ControlStoryboardAction>
                <imedia:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationZ)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="320"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </imedia:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
            </imedia:ControlStoryboardAction>
        </icore:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```